# How to access values from a pouchdb response using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pouchdb

I am trying to get the values returned from a response object using `poucdb-find` but I cannot get the information
here is my code

```
const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  db.find({
    selector: { username: username },
    fields: ["_id", "username", "role", "status", "password"]
  })
    .then(function(user) {
      let doc = user.docs;
      // console.log(user.docs[username]);
      // console.log(doc["values"][1]["username"]);

      if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.docs.values.password)) {
        console.log("user found");
        var token = jwt.sign(
          { username: user.username, role: user.role },
          "my_secret",
          { expiresIn: 3600 }
        );
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "logged in",
          token: token
        });
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "username or password is incorrect"
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.status(403).json({
        message: "user not found",
        err: err
      });
    });
```

when i console log the variable `doc` the response is like this

```
{ docs:
  [ { _id: '0eaaf77e-eae7-448e-becc-9e311cc3adaf',
    username: 'username2',
    role: 'sales',
    password:'...' 
} ]
```

i tried to access the username like this `docs.username`, `docs[username]`, `docs[1]`...but all of them resulted in `undefined`...
so how can i get the `username`? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

```
let doc = user.docs[0];
console.log(doc.username);
```